# Opening an external, non-java file with Java

Tags: java, runtime, command-prompt, ioexception

I am trying to access the file "J:\Java\NetBeansProjects\List of forgoten things\list.eml" and open it using the OS-defined default application. This can be acomplished in the command prompt by calling

```
cd "J:\Java\NetBeansProjects\List of forgoten things"
"list.eml"
```

so I decided to use

```
  Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd \"" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\"\n\r" + "\"" + selectedFile.getName() + "\"");
```

but it keeps giving me an IOException:

```
 java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

does anyone have any experience or advice they would like to share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cd` is not a real executable - it is a shell built-in command.

Additionally, I think what you want to do is use `Desktop` in Java 6, specifically the [`open` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open(java.io.File)), which attempts to open a file with the default registered application on the platform (if it exists).

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html

Comment: but it ran the "shutdown" command, for me... How do I run shell commands, then?

Comment: `shutdown` is a real command in Windows, located in `%WINDIR%/system32`. Please see my edit for a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: Thank you! "java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(selectedFile);" did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

This happens because exec tries to execute the `cd` command as a real file while it's only a command of shell (cmd.exe).

You could try by invoking `cmd /C "cd whateverdir "` to pass the command to shell exe or using a `.bat` file.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `CD` to the directory before executing the file. Just provide the full path.

```
String fileName=System.getProperty("user.dir") + selectedFile.getName();
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(fileName);
```